# Symfony Upload file error on edit form using listener

Tags: php, sql, forms, symfony, file-upload

Today I'was trying to "improve" my file uploads, by creating postLoad function in listener so I can move all code about file from my controller.

This was old add (files are not mandatory):

```
$file = $accommodation->getMainImage()->getFile();
if ($file != null) {
    $fileName = $this->get('app.image_uploader')->upload($file);
    $accommodation->getMainImage()->setFile($fileName);
} else {
    $accommodation->setMainImage(null);
}
```

and this was old edit:

before form submit:

```
if ($accommodation->getMainImage() != null) {
   $oldFile = $accommodation->getMainImage()->getFile();
}
```

after from submit:

```
$file = $accommodation->getMainImage()->getFile();
if ($file != null) {
   $fileName = $this->get('app.image_uploader')->upload($file);
   $accommodation->getMainImage()->setFile($fileName);
} else {
   if (isset($oldFile)) {
       $accommodation->getMainImage()->setFile($oldFile);
   } else {
       $accommodation->setMainImage(null);
   }
}
```

this code works fine, but I wanted to improved it

just form submit get accommodation and persist $accommodation, like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    /** @var AccommodationBase $accommodation */
    $accommodation = $form->getData();
    $entityManager->persist($accommodation);
```

accommodation contain image as one to one

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="accommodationImageMain", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_image_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false, nullable=true)
*/
private $mainImage;
```

and this is image:

```
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "5M",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff"},
     *     maxSizeMessage = "The maximum allowed file size is 5MB.",
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Only image is allowed."
     * )
     */
    protected $file;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AccommodationBase", mappedBy="mainImage")
     */
    private $accommodationImageMain;
```

I added method postLoad to listener step by step using symfony docs

```
class ImageUploadListener
{
    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
    {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity)
    {
        dump($entity);
        if (!$entity instanceof Image) {
            return;
        }

        $file = $entity->getFile();

        // only upload new files
        if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
            return;
        }

        $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
        $entity->setFile($fileName);
    }
    //this is new
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Image) {
            return;
        }

        if ($fileName = $entity->getFile()) {
            $entity->setFile(new File($this->uploader->getTargetDir().'/'.$fileName));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my existing service

```
class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(mt_rand()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDir()
    {
        return $this->targetDir;
    }
}
```

and after everything I can succesfuly upload picture or edit picture on that entity but if I want to add/edit entity without image upload I got this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO image (file,
>   created, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "2017-10-06
>   09:12:16", "2017-10-06 09:12:16"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: image.file
>   I know I can check it in controller and save old picture and before persisting I can add it or set null as I did before. Is there any way how to do it in that Listener/Service?

I know I can do this in controller:

In case of add:

```
if (empty($activity->getActivityLogo()->getFile())) {
   $activity->setActivityLogo(null);
}
```

In case of edit:

before submit:

```
if (!empty($activity->getActivityLogo())) {
   $oldFile = $activity->getActivityLogo()->getFile();
}
```

after submit:

```
if (empty($activity->getActivityLogo()->getFile())) {
   if (empty($oldFile)) {
      $activity->setActivityLogo(null);
   } else {
      $activity->getActivityLogo()->setFile($oldFile);
   }
}
```

but this is the same solution as I had before. Also there is possibility to save Image entity with some "dummy value" which is not good for performance and than a lot's of controlling

Comment: You are saving the name of the image like a `String` and in your database this field is NOT NULL. is correct? You must insert an String `$entiti->setImage("noImageYet")`when your are persisting the entity

Comment: Yes I’m saving it as string, that could be also solution but I prefer save parent entity without image (mainImage = null) and don’t create image object if there is no file

Comment: If I create image object I need to access dB again and check of image has file which is not good